# Is it possible to detect Safari Reader display with Javascript?

Tags: safari, javascript, css

If you have multiple `<article>`s on a page, Safari Reader will only display the first one.  I am writing a long doc; separating the chapters with `<article>` seems semantically correct.  I like giving my mobile web users the ability to keep scrolling and reading forever, so I don't really want to put each `<article>` on a different webpage.  But then again, I don't want users who like Safari reader to only be able to read Chapter 1.

If there were a way to detect Safari reader display, perhaps I could display chapter links in the DOM just when Safari Reader is open.

Any ideas?

Gosh, I really wish Safari reader would horizontal-swipe between articles on the same webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is not possible as Safari Reader mode acts like an extension. And if even it would be possible to detect, I am not sure that adding links or other DOM elements would affect the content of Reader as it is being generated when page loads.